# Can I share an ignore file between mercurial and git?

Tags: git, mercurial, gitignore, hgignore

I use both mercurial and git for similar types of work, and maintain parallel global ignore files. Now, the basic syntax for the two systems is sufficiently similar that I can *almost* use the same ignore file for both systems. But not quite.

- `git` uses (extended) globs to specify ignore patterns.
- `hg` uses either full regular expressions (the default) or extended globs to specify ignore patterns. There is a way to specify which system to use.

So to use the same list of globs for both systems, my `hg` ignore file needs to include a line declaring that the glob syntax is in effect:

```
syntax: glob
# Compilation artifacts
*.o
```

This syntax declaration is not recognized by `git` (which doesn't need one, since it only accepts the glob syntax). I have tried it out and confirmed that it's treated as just another filename: if I create a file called `syntax: glob` (with a space in the name), `git` ignores it. This seems harmless but ugly. So: Is there a way to construct a file of ignore patterns that is **valid** for both systems, without this little wart?

Comment: Your workaround seems pretty harmless, so I would probably stick to that, especially since you don't commit this to a repository. Good comment could help to explain the reason for this hack.